# + Option in custom options

Tags: custom-options

Hi I have created custom options to allow a customer to choose an option when selecting a product, in this case its a choice of drinks when ordering a Meal Deal.  Is it possible to add a + - box option during the category listing of products next to the "Add to Cart" button. This is to allow the customer to increase or decrease the qty of the product without having to click the "Add to Cart" button.  Currently i am using 1.9 and the rwd default theme.  If this is an option it would make selecting multiple same items quicker, rather than the page reload on adding to cart.

Cheers in advance

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So when clicking the + or - button it should update the cart? (in summary)

Comment: Yes that is right, at the moment all i have is the add to cart button but I want a + - box to add or remove on the fly in product category list and product view.